# jQuery image upload & crop by cakephp

Tags: cakephp

In my project, image need to upload and crop. So, I have taken help from http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/klagoggle_myopenid_com/2010/08/25/jquery-image-upload-crop

By this instruction I have created file `jq_imgcrop.php` and with code saved it in `app/controllers/components` and also created `cropimage.php` and saved it `app/views/helpers`

after  that I add the component and the helper in my controller where I want to use the cropload.

code given below

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('BarcodeHelper','Vendor');

/**
 * OesUsers Controller
 *
 * @property OesUser $OesUser
 */

// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
class OesUsersController extends AppController {

      var $helpers = array('cropimage');
      var $components = array('jq_imgcrop');
```

After saved, it is giving me a error that is "Missing Component!!"
In this define directory, have I made any mistake?

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: I ma using cakephp 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The article in the link is written in cakephp 1.x.